# Help understanding proof of estimating finite complex sums in Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, complex-numbers

I'm reading the proof below from Rudin's RCA but there are two equations I can't prove. First, how do we get 
$$|\sum_{S(\theta)} z_k| = |\sum_{S(\theta)} e^{-i\theta} z_k|$$
and how do we get 
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^+(\alpha-\theta)d\theta = 2$$ for every $\alpha$? I would greatly appreciate any proof for these two.

[image]

Comment: $|e^{-i\theta}|=1$

Comment: one of my all time favorite problems!

Comment: $\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \cos t dt = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, notice that $\theta$ is fixed and $\left| e^{-i\theta}\right|=1$

Hence

$$\left| \sum_{S(\theta)}z_k \right|=\left| e^{-i\theta}\right|\left| \sum_{S(\theta)}z_k \right|=\left| \sum_{S(\theta)}e^{-i\theta}z_k \right|$$

For the second part, $\cos \theta$ is $2\pi$ periodic, $\cos ^+(\theta)$ is $2\pi$ periodic too. Hence as long as you integrate over a range of $2\pi$, regardless of where you begin, it gives the same value. Hence $\alpha$ is irrelevant.

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^+(\alpha - \theta)\, d\theta = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^+(\theta)\, d \theta = \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^\frac{\pi}2 \cos \theta \, d \theta = \sin \theta|_{-\frac{\pi}2}^\frac{\pi}2=1-(-1)=2$$